# If selected Datatables row has span, then show div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, datatables, html

So, I have a table with attachments but for example sake I am using a copyright icon. When opening the dialog to view/edit table contents (currently working) I need the .newImage block to show/hide according whether or not the row has a span (copyright icon). http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/8/ and here's the line I am having trouble with.

```
if (properties.eq(0).has('span')) {
                  $('.newImage').show();
              }else{  
                  $('.newImage').hide();
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

`has()` returns a jQuery object, which is always truthy.

Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/R95qn/

```
if (properties.eq(0).find('span').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if (properties.eq(0).find('span').html()) {
  $('.newImage').show();
  }else{  
      $('.newImage').hide();
   }
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/9/